# Wake up printer by network

Tags: windows, printer, hp-laserjet

I have printer HP78E006 (HP LaserJet Pro M404-M405) on my network that is far from my working place. Sometimes it gets offline and I can't print without going to it and turning on. Is it somehow possible to wake-up printer via network?

Comment: How is this printer physically connected, USB to another PC, or LAN? If LAN, are you suing a Standard TCP/IP port?. If TCP/IP, try disabling SNMP status on the port.

Comment: My printer is connected via LAN and uses TCP port 3911. Should I somehow disable SNMP on printer or all PC's that uses this printer?

Comment: 3911 is a strange port. TCP normally uses port 9100 to talk to printers. Try disabling SNMP from Printer Properties > Ports >Configure Port

Comment: Or create a Standard TCP/IP port, from Printer Properties > Ports > Add Port

Answer (score 0):

Considering the strange port number (3911) used for the printer, I would create a new Standard TCP/IP port for the printer.

Go to Printer Properties. Click the Ports tab and then the Add Port button. Enter the printer's IP address. Optionally, you can give the port a name, or you can accept the default name. Untick "SNMP Status Enabled".

Then click OK and see if the problem goes away.